# Android How to pass referrer to play store with intent

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, uri, referrer

we are trying to create a deep link from our website to app. If the app is not installed then user should be taken to the play store and after installing the app he should proceed to location of the deep link.

Key to this is sending referrer query parameter to store (market://details?id=package&referrer=encodedDeeplink) and then process INSTALL_REFERRER in the app. This solution wasn't problem some time ago, but since chrome 25 this kind of auto deep linking doesn't work. You have to use Intent uri instead rather than direct link to play store.

Intent uri should look like this:

```
intent://yourHost/yourPath#Intent;scheme=yourScheme;package=yourPackage;end
```

And when you call this, the chrome browser app checks if the app is installed (I assume with package info) and if so then intent with data = scheme://yourHost/yourPath is launched.
However if the app is not installed then it opens play store for given package name.

My question is: Is there any way how to pass that referrer parameter to play store via intent uri? Need some way how to tell chrome to open store this way.

Thank you

Comment: There is no direct answer there has to be  mechanism at your server end to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct answer, there has to be **mechanism at your server end** to perform this.Meaning you have to save the newly register app via service and pull or push the data to app as you are installing a new application.

Comment: Yea but how should that web service know I am about to install new app instance? That would mean I have to somehow identify current device from web app.

Comment: when user click on the link which will redirects them to play store ask them for unique key or id store it and and application launch just ask them to enter that and via web service and that unique key or id redirect them one of the way.